# Create a cycle in T-SQL from the list

Tags: t-sql

I have code written in C#, but I want to create a T-SQL script to run on the server. This is part of my C# code that I want to convert to T-SQL:

```
var enumerator = distinctlist.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        mtbn dtb = enumerator.Current as mtbn;
        var user = users.Where(x => x.Name == dtb.UserNameTb).FirstOrDefault();
        var action = actions.Where(x => x.Name == dtb.ActionTb.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        var project = projects.Where(x => x.Name == dtb.ProjectNameTb).FirstOrDefault();
        var transaction = transactions.Where(x => x.Name == dtb.TransactioNameTb).FirstOrDefault();
        TransactBoard transactBoard = dbContext.TransactBoard.Add(new TransactBoard
        {
            User = user != null ? user : new EF.User { Name = dtb.UserNameTb },
            Action = action != null ? action : new EF.Action { Name = dtb.ActionTb.Value.ToString() },
            Project = project != null ? project : new Project { Name = dtb.ProjectNameTb, Path = @"S:\\xxxx\\" + dtb.ProjectNameTb },
            Transaction = transaction != null ? transaction : new Transaction { Name = dtb.TransactioNameTb },
            DateTime = dtb.WriteDateTimeTb.Value
        });
        dbContext.MonitorControl.Add(
        new MonitorControl
        {
            ElementId = dtb.ElementIdTb.Value,
            Category = category.Where(x => x.Id == dtb.CategoryIdTb).FirstOrDefault(),
            TransactBoard = transactBoard
        });
    }
```

This is what I did on T-SQL:

```
begin tran            
    insert dbo.TransactionBoard(TrancationId, UserId, ActionId, ProjectId, [DateTime] )
    select t.Id as TrancationId, u.Id as UserId, s.ActionTb, p.Id as ProjectId, s.WriteDateTimeTb
    from monitorControlDb.dbo.MonitorlControlTable s
        left join dbo.[Transaction] t
        on t.[Name] = s.TransactioNameTb 
        left join dbo.[User] u
        on u.[Name] = s.UserNameTb 
        left join dbo.Project p
        on p.[Name] = s.ProjectNameTb
    insert dbo.MonitorControl(ElementId, CategoryId)
    select s.ElementIdTb, s.CategoryIdTb
    from monitorControlDb.dbo.MonitorlControlTable s   
commit
```

Comment: Do you have SQL Profiler (SSMS)? Could you use it to gather the queries which your LINQ is sending to your DB?  It would give some good hints and make it easier to find your answer.

Comment: How to realize a cycle in tsql?

Comment: Actually, your SQL looks perfect. It will automatically cycle through the result set (from your SELECT statements) and insert all rows.   Have you tried it yet?  What is the outcome?

Comment: I have run the script three times and after that TransactionId never comes to MonitorControl even though TransactionBoard has an identity(1,1) and constraint with MonitorControl

Comment: What do you get when you just run the select statements (without the INSERT)? Like `select s.ElementIdTb, s.CategoryIdTb
    from monitorControlDb.dbo.MonitorlControlTable s`  Maybe `monitorControlDb.dbo.MonitorlControlTable` is blank